# zeppelin unable to import pandas, numpy, scipy

Tags: pyspark, apache-zeppelin

Code written in zeppelin, its working and importing fine in shell when I start pyspark there but not in zeppelin with same code.

```
 %pyspark
import pandas

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-4245945050627073162.py", line 239, in <module>
    eval(compiledCode)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because pandas is not installed on the machine.

If pip is not installed, first install pip.

```
sudo curl --silent --show-error https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Then install pandas

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

Or use [docker] like this.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -t knockdata/zeppelin-highcharts
```

> [zeppelin-highcharts](https://hub.docker.com/r/knockdata/zeppelin-highcharts/) image include pandas and Highcharts functionality.

Comment: as I mentioned its working fine when I am importing with PySpark. So If pandas not installed in the machine then how its working with Pyspark?

Comment: Possibly it's not using the same python. check `sys.path` if it's the same. Try to configure it `zeppelin.pyspark.python` in Zeppelin with the same one used in pyspark

Comment: I can't login the machine which host zeppelin. How can I install package in zeppelin notebook?  I mean, use pip in zeppelin notebook .

Comment: @Mithril I know you asked this a long time ago, but it might help someone else in the future. To install from the notebook, create a paragraph and then type:
%sh
pip install pandas

After it is done, restart the python interpreter for import to find the package.